# Информация о OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такие методы как `OnTriggerEnter2D` и `OnTriggerStay2D`.
Как узнать когда объект входит в триггер, а когда начинается фаза `Stay`, я имею ввиду, есть ли какой-то отрезок времени, или это конкретно переход границы коллайдера, где конкретно эта точка перехода `Enter` в `Stay`?

Comment: Прямо в момент входа в коллайдер вызовется 1 раз OnTriggerEnter2D. Далее, начиная со следующего кадра, каждый кадр, пока объект не выйдет из соприкосновения с коллайдером, будет вызываться OnTriggerStay2D. В момент выхода объекта из коллайдера 1 раз вызовется OnTriggerExit2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямо в момент входа в коллайдер, у объекта вызовется 1 раз `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Далее, начиная со следующего кадра, каждый кадр, пока объект не выйдет из соприкосновения с коллайдером, будет вызываться `OnTriggerStay2D`. В момент выхода объекта из коллайдера 1 раз вызовется `OnTriggerExit2D`.

Подробнее: [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html), [OnTriggerStay2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html), [OnTriggerExit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit2D.html).